# Codeigniter+best practice to use foreign key in details table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**As is (working):** I have the following situation:
- a view for a inquiry that has some details(images, additional elements) that are stored in separate tables. Whenever we add a new inquiry I need to create a temporary id, add the details in the additional tables using the temporary id and on save of the inquiry itself I will switch the temporary id with the last inserted id from tbl_iqnuiry.

**Desired solution (presented below):** I know it's not the best solution and that's why I wanted to use Codeigniter's `trans_start()`

For that, I have the following tables:

- `tbl_inquiry` (inquiry_id, customer, col2, col3..)
- `tbl_inquiry_images` (id, inquiry_id, src..)
- `tbl_inquiry_details`(id, inquiry_id, detail1, detail2..)

I have the model, called `Inquiry_model`

```
class Inquiry_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert_inquiry($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_inquiry', $data);        
    }

    public function insert_inquiry_image($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_inquiry_images', $data);        
    }

    public function insert_inquiry_detail($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_inquiry_details', $data);        
    }

    public function update_inquiry($id_inquiry, $data) {
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('inquiry_id', $id_inquiry);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_inquiry');        
    }
}
```

The controller, Inquiry is the following:

```
class Inquiries extends Admin_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function create() 
    {
        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
        {
            $id_inquiry            = $this->input->post('inquiry_id');             
        } 
        else
        {
            /* Begin transaction */
            /* I only add trans_start() in the ELSE part because this is the first place where the view will enter, since we do not post anything. If we would let's say press the Save button, this part will be skipped, but the start_trans had already started */

            $this->db->trans_start();   

            $this->inquiry_model->insert_inquiry($data); 
            $inquiry_id           = $this->db->insert_id();              
        }

        /* definitions and form validations are placed here but not relevant to the scenario itself (multiple fields)*/

        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                /* if nothing to change OR if update succes*/
                if ($this->inquiry_model->update_inquiry($id_inquiry, $data)) {   
                    /* Close transaction */
                    $this->db->trans_complete(); 
                    $this->inquiry_model->update_inquiry($id_inquiry, $data) 
                    redirect('inquiries')
                }
            }
        }

        /* $this->data['elements'] are placed in this area but not relevant to the scenario described (multiple elements)*/

        $this->load->view('inquiries/create', $this->data);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I start the transaction if the view is opened for the first time and if we did not posted anything in that page, else we capture the already generated id

In the view, I use some Ajax to add the details and the images using the `inquiry_id` created in the controller. The insert for details and images works fine.

The issue is that whenever I try to save the inquiry itself, I will have in the `tbl_inquiry` a different id than the one used in `tbl_inquiry_images` and `tbl_inquiry_details`

If you think I am doing it wrong, please let me know, as I have mentioned, I want to improve the way I deal with this kind of inserts

Thank you!

Comment: I see two issues (1) you only start the transaction in the else part of a conditional statement - you should start it at the top of the function before everything else as it should always be called. (2) `$this->inquiry_model->insert_inquiry($data);` where is `$data` coming from - I don't see if defined. Then regarding your question you say "I try to save the inquiry itself, I will have in the tbl_inquiry a different id than the one used in tbl_inquiry_images and tbl_inquiry_details" ... but where is the code inserting updating into these tables? I see the model methods, but not the usage.

Comment: "Whenever we add a new inquiry I need to create a temporary id, add the details in the additional tables using the temporary id and on save of the inquiry itself I will switch the temporary id with the last inserted id from tbl_iqnuiry" this doesn't make sense to me either. Where is this "temporary id". I also have this problem - it is so clear to you the dev, but to someone outside looking in it is very confusing. Please try to clear up some of the explanations and narrow it down a bit ;)

Comment: @Alex: the $data is not described in the example. I wanted to keep the code as tiny as it can be. The second comment from you: that's the existing solution that I do not want to use anymore. I need a better solution to save the data into the database. Imagine you have a product with multiple fields and you will need to add to the newly product not yet saved multiple suppliers. How do you manage to add the suppliers into the database before adding the product itself and also to capture the correct id that you should reference in the suppliers table as foreign id

Comment: Ah so you start "backwards" ... rather than making the engine first you create the body of the car but you want everything to fit. that's kindof an atypical situation; i would insert a blank into the product table and get an id, and that id i would use as reference in the suppliers. so the logic would be if the product doesn't exist when i am inserting into supplier A, i would insert a blank product, get the id, and use that as a related product id field in supplier A table. if the product exists, i would just get the id and use that for the related product id field in supplier A table.

Comment: but i think that's what you are already doing? why are you bent on separating the update/insert functionality anyways? are their different forms involved? because if its just 1 form you can easily do this without a hassle.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I do.. I capture the ID and use it for the additional tables. The issue is that, once I save the Inquiry it will create a new id.. and all my work is gone.. Also, I need to make sure that if I do not save the Inquiry, all related rows from additional tables are deleted as well.. That's why I finished my question with: If you think I am doing it wrong, please let me know, as I have mentioned, I want to improve the way I deal with this kind of inserts. Is there a better solution? How should I do it?

Comment: "I need to make sure that if I do not save the Inquiry, all related rows from additional tables are deleted as well" this is going to be hard to do as a user can just close his laptop and your system will be none the wiser. you could do this with a cron job and just delete all items where `inquery_id`, but how will you know if it's completed or not? there is no real solution for that. i'm assuming you have multiple forms on the same page - maybe you could have a button or a steps form that when the user hits step 3 last form they hit a button that signals the inquiry is done.

Comment: "once I save the Inquiry it will create a new id" - well you could on page load ping your server to get an id e.g. create a blank row and store that id in a js var that you will then update to onsubmit. no lost data. but honestly it seems like this particular page is better suited for a regular post rather than ajax.

Comment: To the downvoter: please can you help me understand for what reason I was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Make a step form. Assuming you have 3 forms based on your 3 tables, start with the most general table which seems like `tbl_inquiry`. On `form_controller/step1` have the user insert some of the details required for the inquiry. on post redirect to or load via ajax step 2 `form_controller/step2`. If using a redirect, simply pass the newly generated id in the url, if ajax, return the id as part of a json object. Importantly, set the `created_at` time.

Continue with this logic/structure until the final step, say, adding images. On that page there could be a button that signifies the inquiry is completed and will mark the inquiry as completed on button press and set a completed flag in the database.

If for some reason the user doesn't complete the form (completed flag is true) in 72 hours from the `created_at` time - with a cron job - delete all related items with the `inquiry_id`.

---

You could also on page load insert a blank into the main table - getting the id, and insert blanks in all of the other tables using the related `inquiry_id` field. This way you have an item in every table. You can then assign this id as a var in js and then all of your queries on that inquiry will be updates rather than inserts - assuring that no data is misplaced.

You can utilize a similar method to delete unfinished forms.

---

It is always difficult with broad questions to answer accurately. I hope I atleast brought up some thinking points. Without knowing exactly what is going on it is difficult to speculate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this one is more or less the same as the actual scenario that I use. Instead of steps I use tabs. It's not what it is desired.. The user wants to have the ability to add all data in single page, without steps, without tabs, all fields should be displayed at once. And trans_start() seems to be the best way to go, but unfortunately I don't know how to use it correctly in this case

Comment: Then don't use ajax and just use a regular post. And I don't see an issue with how you are using transactions except `trans_complete()` shouldn't be called until *after* the last query. You can check its status after calling `trans_complete()` with `$this->db->trans_status()` which returns `bool`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it again! I already did that.. I really tried out all possible solutions and still it seems that I am at the very beginning of coding :(

Comment: I too have a similar system where one table is related to the other and stores project images (after a project is added user gets redirected to project images page to add images). However, in my circumstance, it isn't necessary that a project has images and is left entirely up to the user. If it was required I'd probably keep it all on the same page - the issue lies in that the images also require the proj id be created first as the images would be added via ajax so I would probably then have to use regular files post otherwise I wouldn't be able to keep track of who they belong to.

Comment: That's exactly my issue.. I need the inquiry row to be added the first one.. and then to use it for additional items..

Comment: Yea but like I said you are on the right track - keep it all on one page with one post controller. Insert into the main table first and use the id for the rest of the tables with transactions and stay away from ajax as it isn't really needed for this. If you have any further questions after you redo your controller logic just post it on stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167704/discussion-between-rosuandreimihai-and-alex).